# How do I rollback a dropped table using log?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have dropped a table from a SQL Server 2008 database.

How do I unroll the transaction log to recover the table and latest contents?

The database recovery model is "Full".

Is there any way or third party applications for rollback the dropped table using log?

Answer (score 4):

**Third party software are :**

[ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx). It has free trial as well.

[Toad for SQL Server](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-sql-server/) - It has Log Reader management which Rolls back transactions in the transaction log without the need to restore from a backup

**Native to SQL Server are below methods :**

you can restore your Database from a backup, and then [RESTORE Transaction LOGS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858%28SQL.90%29.aspx) to a point in time with the [**STOPAT**](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/using-stopat-in-the-restore) = '6/10/2013 12:30AM' argument.

Read this excellent post from Paul Randall - [Using fn_dblog, fn_dump_dblog, and restoring with STOPBEFOREMARK to an LSN](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the easiest, least invasive way, is as follows:

1. Restore differential backup (if any) (with no recovery option)
2. Restore all subsequent Transaction Log backups, up to the
   last transaction log backup BEFORE the table was deleted. (with recovery option)

Once you have done this, move the table from the restored database to the live database.

**EDITED**: Removed mention of tail of log

Suggestions / edits to this answer is welcome!

Comment: How to recover transaction 'till specific command? It rollback all transaction, so the 'drop table' command will execute and so on... thanks for your helps

Comment: In your case, you cannot roll back individual transactions, at least not in the way you want to.  You will have to restore a full backup, and then do a POINT IN TIME restore using the transaction log backups. Therefore you need a TLog backup to BEFORE the table was deleted. Any data added to the table between the last TLog backup and the deletion, will be lost.

Comment: You can't restore until the log before the DROP TABLE then restore the tail of the log.

Comment: @mrdenny Ah, my bad... Does he just need to do a Point In Time from the tlog backups then?

Comment: Yep, stopping just before the drop table statement.